# Opening a text file through PLSQL without creating directory

Tags: oracle, file, plsql

Need some help.

I want to open a text file through plsql. But I do not have permission to create a directory object.

Is there any workaround for this approach?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Workaround 1:

Call your DBA and tell him to CREATE DIRECTORY for you (or to grant access to an already existing DIRECTORY).